# Convert iText Barcode Image from CCITT format to PNG

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I'm using iText to create a PDF417 bar code like so:

`private InputStream getBarcode() throws Exception {`

```
BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
barcode.setText("Sample bar code text");

Image image = barcode.getImage();
image.scalePercent(50, 50 * barcode.getYHeight());

return new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getRawData());
```

}

I need to convert the CCITT format returned by `barcode.getImage()` to either JPG, GIF, or PNG so I can include it in a document I'm creating in JasperReports.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this?

```
    BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
    barcode.setText("Bla bla");
    java.awt.Image img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
    BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    outImage.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(outImage, "png", bytesOut);
    bytesOut.flush();
    byte[] pngImageData = bytesOut.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://barcode.png");
    fos.write( pngImageData);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I will keep your code sample handy should I have to convert images in the future.  Turns out I didn't need to convert anything this time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with:

```
private Image getBarcode() throws Exception {

    BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();

    barcode.setText("Sample bar code text");
    barcode.setAspectRatio(.25f);

    return barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
}
```

JasperReports supports the `java.awt.Image` type for images used in a report.